# Помогите немного со словарями в python

Tags: python

Пользователь вводит число K - количество фруктов. Затем он вводит K
фруктов в формате: название фрукта и его количество. Добавьте все фрукты в
словарь, где название фрукта - это ключ, а количество - значение. Вывести
фрукты количество которых максимальное, если таких фруктов несколько
вывести все их.

Comment: Какие трудности? 10-тый день изучения питона. Достаточно подробно описал? А конкретнее: вывести максимальное значение не сложно. А как сделать так, чтобы выводились все (если максимальных несколько) - в этом и вопрос

Comment: 1) Чем 10й день изучения питона мешает сделать простую задачу? Если понимаешь, что ты делаешь, то 10й день - вполне достаточно.  2) Более важно: зачем её делать именно на 10й день, если скорость изучения низкая? Сделайте на 20й или 30й, например.

Comment: Отвечая на конкретный вопрос: вариантов несколько, но самый простой для вас (не самый оптимальный, правда) - сначала определить максимум, что вы уже умеете согласно вашему ответу, затем проверить каждый элемент на равенство этому максимуму и вывести его в таком случае.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создал список, закинул в него данные с клавы, нашел максимальное значение и проверил его по списку, чтобы если что найти несколько значений. Пользуйся :)

```
listFruit = {}
    amount = int(input("amount of fruit: "))
    for i in range(amount):
        name = input("Name fruit: ")
        amountFruit = int(input("Amount: "))
        listFruit[name] = amountFruit
    
    max_value = max(listFruit.values())
    for name, am in listFruit.items():
        if am == max_value:
            print(name)
```

Результат:

```
amount of fruit: 3
Name fruit: Orange
Amount: 3
Name fruit: Apple
Amount: 1
Name fruit: Banana
Amount: 3
Orange
Banana
```